# Why $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is dense in $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-forms

When I read notes about congruence subgroup in modular forms, I was told that the surjectivity of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})$ implies that $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is dense in $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$. I know $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \simeq \lim _{\leftarrow N} \mathbb{Z} / N Z$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is of course dense in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. But why the surjective can show that? I try to use Chinese Reminder Theorem, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't this just saying that for any positive integer $N$, the canonical projection $\operatorname{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z}\right) \to \operatorname{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / N\mathbb{Z}\right)$ is surjective? In this case, this has been proved several times on m.se. (Here's [one thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696539/surjective-map-from-mathrmsl2-mathbbz-to-mathrmsl2-mathbbz-n).)

Comment: I have know how to prove the projection is surjective ,but I don't know why then it shows the dense.

Comment: I don't know how the topology on $\operatorname{SL}_2\left(\widehat{\mathbb Z}\right)$ is defined, but I would suspect that a sequence of matrices $\left(A_i\right)_{i \geq 0}$ approaches a matrix $A$ whenever for each positive integer $N$, there exists a $j \geq 0$ such that all $i \geq j$ satisfy $\operatorname{proj}_{\mathbb Z / N \mathbb Z}\left(A_i\right) = \operatorname{proj}_{\mathbb Z / N \mathbb Z}\left(A\right)$ (where $\operatorname{proj}_{\mathbb Z / N \mathbb Z}$ denotes the projection onto $\operatorname{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / N\mathbb{Z}\right)$). In that case, the ...

Comment: ... surjectivity should do the trick.