# If $a,c$ are coprime integers, what is the probability that $a+d$ and $c$ are coprime?

Tags: probability, coprime

Suppose $p$ is a prime number and suppose we are working modulo $p$. Moreover, suppose we know that $a$ and $p-1$ are two coprime integers ($a < p$). What is the probability that $a +d \bmod p$ is coprime with respect to $p-1$ as well? I mean. Are the events $B=$"$a$ is coprime wrt $p-1$" and $A=$"$a + d \bmod p$ is coprime wrt $p-1$"  independent or not? Moreover, what could be the probability $P(A | B)$?

I think the answer is strictly linked to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862807/show-that-for-x-y-z-in-mathbbz-if-x-and-y-are-coprime-then-exists-n) where we can use $p-1$ as $b$ and $c$ (nobody says $b \neq c$ in that question). Now, if $gcd(a,p-1) =1$ then there exists $x$ such that $gcd(a+x(p-1),p-1)=1$. Furthermore , here there is a statement about the number of such $x$'s. They are $\phi(p-1)$ and "they are  also at least as frequent as integers $x$ satisfying $gcd(x,p-1)=1 $ ".

Coming back to my questions, if $a$ and $p-1$ are coprime, then the probability that $a+d \bmod p$ and $p-1$ of being coprime is equal to the probability that $d = x(p-1)$ for $x$ coprime wrt $p-1$.

Suppose we are working in a range $[0,n(p-1)]$. Then the probability of $d$ being a multiple of $p-1$ in that range is $1/p-1$. Moreover, the probability of $x$ being coprime wrt $p-1$ should be more or less $6/\pi^2$.

Finally, the probability we are looking for is $$P(A | B) = \dfrac{6}{\pi^2 (p-1)} $$

Can this reasoning work?

Comment: If you are asking for the probability that $\gcd((a+d) \mod p , p-1) = 1$ given that $\gcd(a \mod p, p-1) = 1$, then it certainly won't be $\frac{6}{\pi^2(p-1)}$. Instead it will be the fraction of $d \in \{0, 1, ..., p-1 \}$ for which $\gcd((a+d) \mod p , p-1) = 1$

Comment: Yes, i'm looking for this answer. Is there a formula in $d$ or $p-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $d$ goes from $0$ to $p-1$, $(a+d) \mod p$ would also go from $0$ to $p-1$ no matter what $a$ is. Therefore $A$ and $B$ are independent and $P(A) = P(B) = P(A|B)$.

Note that $$P(A)=P(B)=P(A|B) = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left[ \gcd(n, p-1)=1 \right]}{p} = \frac{\phi(p-1)}{p}$$

for $p \ge 3$, where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)